# How to test and check a json files and make a report of the errors

Tags: python, json, testing, report, jsonschema

I am currently using `jsonschema` with `python` to check my json files. I have created a `schema.json` that checks the json files that are looped over, and I display the file is invalid or valid according to the checks i have added in my `schema.json`.
Currently i am not able to display and highlight the error in the json file which is being checked, for example

```
    "data_type": {
      "type": "string",
      "not": { "enum": ["null", "0", "NULL", ""] }
    },
```

if the json file has the value `"data_type" : "null"` or anything similar in the enum, it will display `json file is invalid` but i want it to highlight the error and display `you added null in the data_type field` can i do it with jsonschema?

If there is another way without using `jsonschema` that will work; the main testing is to check multiple json files in a folder (which can be looped over) and check whether they are valid according to few set of rules and display a clean and nice report which specifically tells us the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is used `Draft7Validator` from `jsonschema` and it allows to display error message

```
validator = jsonschema.Draft7Validator(schema)
errors = sorted(validator.iter_errors(jsonData[a]), key=lambda e: e.path)
            for error in errors:
                print(f"{error.message}")
                report.write(f"In {file_name}, object {a}, {error.message}{N}")
                error_report.write(f"In {file_name}, object {a},{error.json_path[2:]} {error.message}{N}")
```

This prints -

> In test1.json, object 0, apy '' is not of type 'number'

> In test2.json, object 0, asset 'asset_contract_address' is a required property

Helpful link that helped me achieve this- [Handling Validation Errors](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors/#jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError.json_path)